# Is an OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket TLS?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, is an [`OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/SSL/SSLSocket.html) an implementation of [RFC 2246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2246)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it provides a SSL/TLS client or server socket. With the cipher list on the OpenSSL Context object you can pass to the initializer, you can control which protocol exactly  is spoken by that socket.

The OpenSSL classes of ruby are a rather thin wrapper around the base OpenSSL API. So you might want to read [its cipher documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html) too.

Comment: Thank you, I think I'll read through all the docs I can get. Are you able to answer a second question I have about OpenSSL?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Ruby's SSL implementation does support TSL v1.0 and higher by utilizing the OpenSSL library that is installed on your system. By default, the behavior will be lenient, and Ruby will choose the "best" protocol being supported by the peer, but if you want finer-grained control and enforce an actual protocol, you may do this by setting appropriate values with [OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext#ssl_version=](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/SSL/SSLContext.html).

That said, the newest versions of TLS, 1.1 and 1.2, will only be supported if you have one of the recent OpenSSL versions installed on your system. It is highly recommended to continuously upgrade, only the newest versions receive all the security-related bug fixes!